# iOS MapBox maps lagging

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mapbox

I'm using MapBox for my app. I need to draw a straight line between my current position and given marker. This line should be updated with every location update. So i have written this code

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MGLUserLocation?){
    drawPath()        
}

func drawPath(){
    if(shouldDrawLine){      
        mapView.removeOverlay(line)
        let userLoaction = mapView.userLocation!.coordinate
        linePoints = [userLoaction, destination]
        shouldDrawLine = true
        line = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &linePoints, count: 2)
        mapView.addOverlay(line)
    }
}
```

And I got picture like this:

But it's lagging so much! Black line is blinking every couple seconds.

How can i optimise it?

Answer (score 0):

it's blinking so much because you're redrawing the line each time a location update occures, this could be every second, depending on your update settings. to reduce the updates you could calculate the distance to the new location with `distanceFromLocation` and redraw the line when it's neccesary. or reduce the [update interval time](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MotionBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH38-SW1) 
but in general when you remove a polyline and set a new one, there will be always a blink effect. you could try to set the new line first an remove the old line afterwards. this oculd reduce the blinking.